# If I have a handler interceptor that loads a user object, adds it to request attri, do I cast to get object?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

I plan to create a Handler interceptor that will fire before the controller gets called (or I'll do this pre-action firing).

I will then check the user's cookie, and load the user object based on the sessionid in the cookie.

I will then add the user object to the request attributes.

Now if I want to retrieve the user object in my controllers action, do I cast it to (User) ?

I believe in my freemarker template I can just do ${user.name} correct?  or is it user.getUsername ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you'd better place the user in the session, so that the cookie > user conversion does not happen on each request.

Second, you can just get it from there (session/request) by calling

```
User user = (User) session.getAttribute(USER_KEY); // this is s String constant
```

Alternatively, you can make a class `UserHolder`, where you pass an `HttpSession` and it gives you the user, thus sparing the casts in your controller cote.

The same approach can be used with `HttpServletRequest`.

Comment: I dont' want to use sessions as this is for a distributed application and it can't rely on talking to the same server.

Comment: you can, it's called session replication ;)

Comment: i'd rather go the cookie with sessionID route, its more scalable and less error prone and doesnt' require JVM's to chat with each other.

Comment: ok, as you wish. My answer holds for both session and request.